# Watermark magento 2

Tags: watermark

most of the time the logo of the shops is apearing correctly on the product picture but it also happens that we are seeing a black bar on the right bottom.

The thumbnail is showing correct in the cart page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue of png depth image type.

If your png image has 32 but depth then your product image will appear well with watermark.

For that you might have to convert your png image to 32 bit depth.

If this helps then hit LIKE.

Enjoy your coding!!! :)

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback.
We've checked some images but it's the same for all images.

Do you have some other ideas?

[image]